# How can I group by name in R and apply sum to the other 2 columns?

Tags: r, group-by, aggregate

I am trying to summarize this dataset by grouping by name (Almeria, Ath Bilbao,...) and have the sum of its corresponding values in column 2 (HalfTimeResult) and 3 (FullTimeResult). I tried with the **aggregate** and **group_by** functions but have not been able to obtain the right output.

What function and how would I use it to obtain an output like this?

[image]

This is the dataset that I am working with:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = HomeTeam]
```